# How to append an element multiple times?

Tags: jquery

I want to append an element multiple times like the following but it is appending more than 33 items:

```
for(var i=0;i<33;i++){
    $('.selector').clone().appendTo('#another');
}
```

The problem is occuring as it's cloning and appending all cloned elements. How should I do?

Also, How can I add classes for all .selector like some-1, some-2, ...., some-32?

```
var el = $('.selector');
for(var i=0;i<33;i++){
    el.clone().appendTo('#another');
    $('.selector').addClass('some-'+i);
}
```

But it adds to selector some-1,some-2 to each selector but I wanted to do some-1 for first selector some-2 for second selector like so.

Comment: do you have more than one matching item ?

Comment: .selector is cloned and now it's becoming two selector and then cloning and appending that's the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only clone the first one:

```
var el = $('.selector');
for(var i=0;i<33;i++){
    el.clone().appendTo('#another');
}
```

Doing this also improves performance as you cache the element (you don't have to search for it in the DOM tree every time you use `$('.selector').`).

Updated demo, also ads a different class for each new element. http://jsfiddle.net/mvpF9/

`el.clone().addClass('some-'+i).appendTo("#another");`

Comment: then you should make a ref outside of the loop to '#another' as well. var another = $('#another');

Comment: Yes, but that's not as important as the `.selector` element, as every time you use it, it actually searches for all the elements with that class and returns a list of them, and then you would have to filter that list (in this case only get the first element). But you are right, that could also be an improvement if performance is really an issue. :)

Comment: so, how can I add different classes like some-1, some-2 for the selector

Comment: What do you mean? Add classes for the newly added element? `el.clone().addClass('some-'+i).appendTo("#another");` ?

Answer (score 1):

Only select the first element

```
for(var i=0;i<33;i++){
    $('.selector').first().clone().appendTo('#another');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in another answer here, just cache the original `.selector`, and clone that.

To add a class to each clone, just use `addClass()` and use the value of `i`.

```
var $selector = $('.selector');

var clones = [];
for (var i=1; i<33; i++) {
    clones.push( $selector.clone().addClass( 'someClass' + i )[0] );
}

$(clones).appendTo('#another');
```

For performance, the above adds each cloned element to an array, and constructs a jQuery object from it so that the `appendTo()` method only needs to be called once.

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sunsb/6/)